# Flash error or success message to user after fetch/ajax request

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, fetch-api, flash-message

I have an app that currently uses the fetch api to make AJAX requests for CRUD operations. In case of success or error, my server sends a response containing an array of error/success messages like:
`['Missing email field', 'Password is too short']`

If I wasn't using AJAX and instead reloading/rerendering the page, there are modules like `connect-flash` and `express-session` that allow you to flash error/success message to the user.

How can I achieve the same when doing AJAX requests with the fetch API? One method I thought of was creating a `div` on my view and then adding the error/success as `li` elements on that view via JS. However, I was wondering if there was a module that does all this for you like there is for when re-rendering the pages.

Further, if I use the approach described above of modifying the DOM with the messages, those messages persist on the view. I only want to show the messages for limited amount of time to the user.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
I am only using `express-handlebars` and `bootstrap` modules so not using any big frameworks like Vue/React/Angular.

Comment: There are various libraries and means of doing this, as it stands this is far too open for opinion and debate - try narrow the scope of the question by describing your existing UI and what frameworks you are using perhaps? e.g. Vue / React / Angular etc.

Comment: I added that to the edit. I am only using Bootstrap and Handlebars. Not using any front end framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap, I'd recommend looking at their [Alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) component, it supports the ability to [dismiss](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing) via the UI or programmatically